# Find the click through rate for "App Invites" on "Facebook Insights"

Tags: facebook-insights, click-through, facebook-invite-friends

I am trying to find the click through rate for "App Invites" on "Facebook Insights". We have implemented invites in our game and have advertisements on Facebook as well. I would like to know how many people install the app after being invited by a Facebook friend. This is a very simple thing but it does not seem to be in Facebook insights.

Answer (score 1):

You should see the CTR in the [Facebook Analytics for Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/analytics) > Integrations > Invites

[image]

Comment: Invites in the is not in my Integrations tab. We do them. Why would they not be there?